# Java timer cannot find symbol

Tags: java, timer

I've created a new `java.util.Timer` `Timer timer = new Timer();` alongside an object of my TextTimer class `TextTimer tt = new TextTimer();`.

When I try `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 35);`, I get an error saying: **cannot find symbol** at the `tt` parameter in the `scheduleAtFixedRate` function. I've used this way of working in a different class, where it has no problems at all.

```
public HelloTVXlet() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TextTimer tt = new TextTimer();
    tt.setCallback(this);

     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 35); // error at tt parameter
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,long,long)) takes a [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) as it's first parameter. You're passing it a `TextTimer`, which is presumably not a `TimerTask`.

Comment: Does it matter that my TextTimer class doesn't have _Task_ in the name? Because I'm also trying the same code in a different class where i **am** using EntityReset**Task** as object, leading to the same error.

Comment: @Regentix It can be called whatever you like. It needs to `extend TimerTask`

Comment: Yes!! I knew i forgot something, thats it!!

Comment: @Regentix Sure. Happy to help.